# Understanding the autocorrelation of random walk

Tags: autocorrelation, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I have been trying to derive the autocorellation for a random walk. I obtained the following result:
$\rho_k(t)=\frac{\operatorname{Cov}\left(x_t, x_{t+k}\right)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}\left(x_t\right) \operatorname{Var}\left(x_{t+k}\right)}}=\frac{t \sigma^2}{\sqrt{t \sigma^2(t+k) \sigma^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k / t}}$

I wanted to verify this, and came along a source online: [link](http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/%7Ekchan/s156.spring03/chap2.pdf). As can be seen on page four of this document, they derived the autocorrelation to be

$ \rho_{t, s}=\frac{\gamma_{t, s}}{\sqrt{\gamma_{t, t} \gamma_{s, s}}}=\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}} \quad \text { for } 1 \leq t \leq s$ (2.2.13)

given
$\gamma_{t, s}=t \sigma_a^2 \quad \text { for } 1 \leq t \leq s $ (2.2.12)

How did they get $\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}$ to be the autocorrelation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot get why it doesn't follow easily: since $\gamma_{s, t}= t\sigma^2_a$ for $1\leq t\leq s, $ then $$\rho_{t, s}=\frac{\gamma_{t, s}}{\sqrt{\gamma_{t, t} \gamma_{s, s}}}=\frac{t\sigma^2_a}{\sqrt t\sigma_a\sqrt s \sigma_a}=\sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}.$$